# Finding a duplicate key in Microsoft Acccess

Tags: key

I need to create a form in Microsoft Access where when the user inputs a number, then Access either takes the user to the number if it is in the primary key. If not, the number which is then input becomes a new primary key.

Does anyone know if this is possible? - thanks